# What does the following code do in regards to structure pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, malloc, structure

```
struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The above code is part of a larger program that creates a linked list. I already have and understand the code that leads up to this which creates the structure "node". I just am unsure what the code I provided does in regards to that structure.

Comment: It allocates storage for one `struct node`. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: ...and initializes `link` to point to that allocated storage.

Comment: *link is a pointer to a structure, but your data needs to exist somewhere in memory, so malloc creates ( allocate ) space for a structure of size same as node.

Comment: You may like to view and compare [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) and [Singly Linked List of Integers](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) for variations on how to handle singly linked lists (the first uses no *tail* pointer and iterates to add a node at the end, the second uses both a *head* and *tail* pointer to avoid the iteration on insert)

Answer (score 0):

The above code simply ***allocates*** memory of dimension **"struct node"**, then ***cast*** it to the same type and ***assign the returned pointer to a variable*** called link.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's go through it piece by piece....

First, this tells that you are after a pointer to a struct of type `node` **not** a *struct node* but a pointer that points to a memory location holding a *struct node*

```
struct node *link = ...
```

then, let's have a look at [the signature of the malloc() function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=malloc&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

It tells us that the return type is `void *`, which , in C, can be casted to any other type and generally used to provide a universal interface to the caller (similar to but not same as templates in C++ or other languages).

With the below cast, we are casting `void *`, the return type of `malloc()` to a pointer to a struct of type node, i.e. `struct node*`

```
(struct node*) malloc(...);
```

Looking at the argument passed to the `malloc()` function, which gives the size of an expression measured in char-sized storage units (`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1)

```
...sizeof(struct node)...
```

you are asking your compiler to return you the size of your `struct node` (this, of course, depends on the members of your struct).

Putting it all together...

```
struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

*allocate memory as big as a struct of type node can fit and return me a pointer to the start of this memory chunk. At the same time, mark this chunk of memory so that you (the compiler) will know that this area is reserved for a struct of type node*

**Edit** : In C, you do not need to cast the type of the pointer returned by *malloc()* to another pointer type. In your case, the returned `void *` pointer from *malloc()* is automatically promoted to the appropriate pointer type, i.e. `struct node*`.